# Is it possible to display the sum over batches instead of the mean over batches as loss in keras?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

I have a regression task and am measuring fit using Euclidean distance. Instead of displaying the mean squared error as the loss, I want to display the sum of squares. That is, I want to **only** sum over the square error terms and **not** divide by the number of examples.

On a batch level I can achieve this by defining a custom loss like so (maybe I could instead use `tf.keras.losses.MeanSquareError` directly):

```
class CustomLoss(tf.keras.losses.Loss):
    def call(self, Y_true, Y_pred):
        return tf.reduce_sum(tf.math.abs(Y_true-Y_pred) ** 2, axis=-1)

target_loss=CustomLoss(reduction=tf.keras.losses.Reduction.SUM)
```

Which will compute the square error for each example and then instruct TensorFlow to SUM over the examples to compute the batch loss instead of the default `SUM_OVER_BATCH_SIZE` (which should not be read literally, but as a fraction, i.e., `SUM / BATCH_SIZE`).

My problem is that, on an epoch level, Keras takes these sums and then computes the mean across steps (batches) to report the loss of the epoch. **How do I get Keras to compute the sum over batches instead of the mean?**

Answer (score 0):

You will have to write a [Custom Callback](https://keras.io/callbacks/#create-a-callback) which will append losses after each batch to the list(as shown in shared link doc).

Implement the
`on_epoch_end` to get the sum of all the values in the list(where you added all the batch losses)

If you want to minimize sum of losses over all the batches, use `K.Function` API. [Full implementation](https://towardsdatascience.com/keras-custom-training-loop-59ce779d60fb)

Answer (score 0):

You can sum over the batches in `tf.keras.metric.Metric` like below, but right now there is an open issue pending in 2.4.x (please see [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/47099)), you can try with 2.3.2 though,

```
class AddAllOnes(tf.keras.metrics.Metric):
  """ A simple metric that adds all the one's in current batch and suppose to return the total ones seen at every end of batch"""
    def __init__(self, name="add_all_ones", **kwargs):
        super(AddAllOnes, self).__init__(name=name, **kwargs)
        self.total = self.add_weight(name="total", initializer="zeros")

    def update_state(self, y_true, y_pred, sample_weight=None):    
        self.total.assign_add(tf.cast(tf.reduce_sum(y_true), dtype=tf.float32))
        
    def result(self):
        print('')
        print('inside result...', self.total)
        return self.total

X_train = np.random.random((512, 8))
y_train = np.random.randint(0, 2, (512, 1))

K.clear_session()
model_inputs = Input(shape=(8,))
model_unit = Dense(256, activation='linear', use_bias=False)(model_inputs)
model_unit = BatchNormalization()(model_unit)
model_unit = Activation('sigmoid')(model_unit)
model_outputs = Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')(model_unit)
optim = Adam(learning_rate=0.001)
model = Model(inputs=model_inputs, outputs=model_outputs)
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer=optim, metrics=[AddAllOnes()], run_eagerly=True)
model.fit(X_train, y_train, verbose=1, batch_size=32)
```